# Java Equality not Behaving as Expected

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an android application that uses a subclass of SimpleListAdapter to bind a ListActivity.  The list that the Adapter binds to is of type `List<HashMap<String, Object>>`.

I have to following If statement in the list Adapter...

```
if (dataRow.get("HasLineup1").toString()) == "0")
```

This never evaluates to `true` for me, even when the Eclipse debugger says that `dataRow.get("HasLineup1").toString()` is equal to `"0"` in the inspection window.

The list of data is populated from an XML source with the line

```
Game.put("HasLineup1", attributes.getNamedItem("home_lineup").getNodeValue());
```

I managed to work around the issue by changing the If statement to

```
if (Integer.parseInt(dataRow.get("HasLineup1").toString()) == 0)
```

Can someone explain to me why the first If statement I used wasn't working?  Java isn't my native language, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong based on my .Net background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator compares the instance memory location for non-primitive types therefore this fails unless the two sides of the operand are the same instance. Whenever dealing with non-primitive types, use `equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: ... and Strings in Java are objects! However, you can use method internal to pick a unique reference for the string. In this case, you can use "==" (e.g., dataRow.get("HasLineup1").toString()).internal() == "0".internal() )

Comment: @Matteo It's `intern()`, not `internal()`. And you'd do best not to abuse it too much unless you're pretty certain of what you're doing.

Comment: @G_H sorry... I do not check the javadoc, but I knew that the method returns the *internal* representation for the string. I agree that that method should not be over-used (but I'd like to mention its existence)

Comment: @Matteo Fair enough. It's not all that commonly used though. Probably because it's easy to slip into mistakes. I think `equals` of the String implementation in Sun's JDK and OpenJDK first checks with `==` to catch the simplest case (same object) first, so using `intern()` can improve performance even without using `==` instead of `equals`.

Comment: @G_H I confirm that the Sun (Oracle) implementation of String.equals first performs a "==" check. However, the intern method relies on an internal pool of strings. If a string equal to the one passed, the pool is updated (by inserting the given one). Consequently, I use that method only when I want to perform a really fast comparison (and comparing references is really fast!)

Comment: @Matteo Yah, I know the `intern()` functionality. So, `s1.intern().equals(s2.intern())` should see the performance gain, won't it? Assuming neither is null, of course. I've used it by simply replacing some String fields in objects by their interned versions, so they point to the same String instance across objects if they're the same character sequence. Even so, I've kept using `equals` since you no-one assures you the pool can't have entries removed if it grows too big. It's hairy stuff, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `string` you should do it with `equals` method.

```
if (dataRow.get("HasLineup1").toString())equals("0"))
```

Comment: I tested and this works, but can you explain why my original If statement doesn't work?  I'm not just interested in fixing my immediate problem, I want to actually understand what's happening.

Comment: As I state in my answer, `==` compares memory locations not equality.

Comment: String is an object. Each object has an objectid. It checks whether it is the same object or not. You check with "0" which is a new object for java and has another objectid

Comment: @bradley-uffner additionally they reference to different memory locations.

Answer (score 2):

The equality **operator** `==` will do the following, based on what you're comparing:

- Two primitive types (e.g. `int`, `char`, ...): check if their values are the same.
- Two non-primitive types (class instances): check if the compared references point to the same object in memory.

In other words, for non-primitives `==` doesn't imply semantics. You'll want the `equals` method for that. It's defined on `Object` so it'll always be available. But its semantics are determine by how (and if) a specific class decides to override this method.

For String, it's a character-by-character comparison with the argument of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link with references about the differences between == and equals.  == compares references, while equals() compares the values.

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (dataRow.get("HasLineup1").toString()).equals("0"))
```

`==` (double equals) only compares the objects to see if they point to the same place in memory. the `equals` method actually compares the characters in the two strings to one another.

Answer (score 0):

You must use method "equals" or call .internal() on both strings before using "==".

Comment: Best not to point someone who's new to Java to `intern()`, even if it's technically correct.

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer to explain all the options... I would use internal if I have to quickly verify if a string is the same of one of a pool of (several) strings.